# How to calculate this function

Tags: continued-fractions

Please, I would like to calculate this function which contains an infinite continued fraction

```
f[y_]=1/(1 + ContinuedFractionK[-(((n + 1) (n + 3))/((2 n + 3) (2 n + 5))) y^2 A, 1, {n, 0, Infinity}])
```

But no results, Mathematica returns the same continued fraction.

[image: function]

Please, Is there a method to construct this infinite fraction and evaluate f[y]?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is correct, but because you have undefined `A` in the formula, it results in the expression. And, most likely, *Mathematica* can't find any simpler form for this expression either.

Compare this:

```
f[y_] := 
 1/(1 + ContinuedFractionK[-(((n + 1) (n + 3))/((2 n + 3) (2 n + 
             5))) y^2 A, 1, {n, 0, Infinity}])

f[1]
(* ...formula view... *)

f[1] /. A -> 1
(* 3/2 *)

(* with A = 1 *)
g[y_] := 
 1/(1 + ContinuedFractionK[-(((n + 1) (n + 3))/((2 n + 3) (2 n + 
             5))) y^2, 1, {n, 0, Infinity}])

g[1]
(* 3/2 *)
```

Or just define as a function of two variables:

```
h[y_, A_] := 
 1/(1 + ContinuedFractionK[-(((n + 1) (n + 3))/((2 n + 3) (2 n + 
             5))) y^2 A, 1, {n, 0, Infinity}])

h[1, 1]
(* 3/2 *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response m0nhawk. Therefore no possibility to calculate the general term of this continuous fraction. Can this question intervene in my case: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103164/truncate-an-infinite-continued-fraction-at-order-2000

Answer (score 3):

Letting $t=A y^2$, we can simplify our considerations to the following function of one variable:

```
maj[t] == 1/(1 + ContinuedFractionK[-(((n + 1) (n + 3))/((2 n + 3) (2 n + 5))) t, 1,
                                     {n, 0, Infinity}])
```

Once again, the [Lentz-](https://doi.org/10.1364/AO.15.000668)[Thompson-Barnett](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-9991%2886%2990046-X) algorithm can be used for numerical evaluation:

```
maj[t_?InexactNumberQ] := Module[{a, c, d, e2, ee, f, h, k},
    ee = 10^(-Precision[t]); e2 = ee^2;
    f = c = 1; d = 0; k = 0;
    While[k++;
          a = -((k (k + 2))/((2 k + 1) (2 k + 3))) t;
          d = 1 + a d; If[d == 0, d = e2]; d = 1/d;
          c = 1 + a/c; If[c == 0, c = e2];
          f *= (h = c d);
          Abs[h - 1] > ee];
    1/f]
```

which can be plotted:

```
Plot[maj[t], {t, -3, 1}]
```

[image: plot]

```
Plot3D[maj[A y^2], {A, -2, 0}, {y, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 45]
```

[image: 3D plot]

Comment: J. M., many thanks for your answer. Please can you explain me this algorithm?

Comment: I linked to the two papers explaining the evaluation method for your CF; please refer to them if you want to know details.

Comment: J. M., thank you so much. Please, can you apply the same algorithm to this fraction `1/(1 + x y + ContinuedFractionK[(n (n + 1) I (x/B)) - (n (n + 2))/(4 (n + 1)^2 - 1)x^2 A, 1, {n, 1, Infinity}])`?

Comment: That should prolly be [a separate question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: It's the same question but modified!

Comment: J. M., this is my separate question  [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/219873/how-to-evaluate-and-integrate-this-continued-fraction)

Comment: J. M.'s technical difficulties, are you connected? I need your help please.